# copy of metadata including appropriate security certificate during SSO Authentication from our APP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on

During SSO Authentication from Azure for my app, Security Team is asking for copy of metadata including appropriate security certificate.

Also info regarding OID numbers for the attributes (e.g. name, mail address)

Please help me to setup this for my application to support SSO login

I new to this, unable to understand this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.